# Mobile testing with appium/Android - can't access webelements in the mobile app

Tags: android, selenium, mobile, appium

Android mobile app testing with appiumv1.6.5 and java-client-3.2.0.
I can't access webelements in the mobile app home page. Home page is loaded, but there is an other window loaded saying "session is expired". No way to move that new window.

`driver.switchTo().activeElement()/driver.switchTo().alert()` gives:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented

I checked the page source, when I call `driver.getPageSource()`, it is hanging. I have to close mobile app through the device to move to the next step in the code.

Comment: Here is my code

Comment: capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, Platform.ANDROID);
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Platform.ANDROID);
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emu"); 
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.faber.worker");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.faber.worker.MainActivity"); 
driver  =  new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);         
Thread.sleep(15000);
driver.switchTo().activeElement().click();

Comment: What is the text of the button you want to click on that window

Comment: It has Cancel/Submit button with username/password fields. it has this message "Your session has expired. Please enter your password to continue". This is like a popup or alert window. under this window I can see my home page with username/passwrd fied and login button.
There is no way to put values to these fields and driver.find methods not working. It says elements is not there.
I tried like, driver.findElementByXPath("(//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc='Faber'])[1]").click();

Answer (score 0):

With new UI Automator you don't need to use switchTo method. Make you sure that you device's Android System WebView is up to date else you need to update through Google PlayStore. Once you update Android System WebView and try capture the elements using UIAutomator as you do normally and should see the elements inside webview in the UIAutomator's screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Vinod,
when I tried to view home page through appiumv1.6.5 (start New session -->startSession) using following code
{  "platformName": "Android",
  "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
  "app": "D:\\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\\Faber.apk",
  "appPackage": "com.faber.worker",
  "appActivity": "com.faber.worker.MainActivity"}
it is not loaded complete home page. Since it is getting more than 10 seconds to load my mobile test app. Appium is expecting it before 10 seconds.When I try to "Refresh source and screenshot" after completely loaded the home page, then it is hanging. Any help?

Comment: First you need to check whether the Automator detects your elements or not,that you can't know directly by running code. Stop your execution. Open your Android SDK folder and open uiautomator from that. Capture the screen, it should list all the elements which are visible on the device with image

Comment: Hi Vinod, Yes it is detect the home page with that popup/alerts window. No issues to view and get element names. But from my test I can't access these elements.
 It says elements is not there. when I try like, driver.findElementByXPath("(//android.widget.TextView[@conte‌​nt-desc='Faber'])[1]‌​").click();

Comment: Give some time to load the page completely and then try. You can use timeouts

Comment: Hi Vinod,
I was trying to print the page source after 20 seconds. Then it was hanging there without printing the page source. I can see the test steps executed up to that step. So then I closed app from my device to get print page source on my eclipse log.
driver  =  new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);         
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         Thread.sleep(20000);
System.out.println("Before printing the Page source" );  
System.out.println("Page source is = "+driver.getPageSource() ); //hanging